# Spotfire Document Property setting using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, spotfire

I have created JS script that capture user inputs and publish them in another hidden input document. 
I confirmed it works because I made the hidden input visible and publish all the input as delimited string.
So far it works fine
but when I try to use the property document in another textarea, ironpython etc.. within the same DXP it is returning blank, even though I can see the string published in the previous text area.

I used this html tags ...
   for input property to display the captured data.

jQuery to capture all the inputs
inval=$.....
......
....

then used this to publish them in the input field $('#dfdklsfksldfkslfs').text(inval).blur()
so far all works fine.

but after this when trying to use the document property in textarea, irontpython, within the same DXP, it is returning (BLANK) even though I can see them published in the textarea. 
am I missing any steps? do I need to reassign some features?

also I have tried $('#dfdklsfksldfkslfs').val(inval).blur()  this won't even publish the data in the inputfield. 
here is the update with code

```
html
<div id='dispInput'> <spotfirecontrold id='dfdklsfksldfkslfs'></div> 
 jquery
$('button')click(function(){
inval=$('input').map(function(){
  return $(this).val(); }).get().join('-');

$('#dfdklsfksldfkslfs').text(inval).blur() //this publish the result but don't assign the data to the document property

})
```

I am completely lost.
thanks a lot

Comment: Showing some code would help

Comment: more code please. and tag as jquery too.

Comment: code added, mostly the code work  up to publishing the result, but not as assigning the values to the document property.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting timeout in the function (500ms will do).

```
$('button')click(function(){
    setTimeout(function (){
       inval=$('input').map(function(){
          return $(this).val(); }).get().join('-');

    $('#dfdklsfksldfkslfs').text(inval).blur()
}), 500
});
```

Hope this helps.